# Confusion with gauge symmetry and spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

Suppose we have an electron with some arbitrary spin. This means that a 360 degree rotation in space will cause a phase shift of 180 degrees. However, the electron description (Dirac Equation) is written as locally invariant for any U(1)/phase gauge transformation. My question is, how was it shown mathematically or experimentally that this phase shift occurs if it is impossible to measure the phase shift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dirac lagrangian is indeed invariant under the global phase shift of the spinor. However, this should not be interpreted as a rotation with respect to spin degrees of freedom.

In the spinorial representation of the Lorentz group, rotations are implemented by the following matrix
$\quad \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad S[\vec{\phi}]=
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{\frac{i}{2} \vec{\phi}\cdot \vec{\sigma}}&0 \\
0&e^{\frac{i}{2} \vec{\phi}\cdot \vec{\sigma}}
\end{bmatrix}$

where $\vec{\phi}$ denotes the angular parameters of the rotation and $\vec{\sigma}$ is the Pauli vector.

Now, suppose we rotate by $2\pi$ about the z-axis. This corresponds to $\vec{\phi}=(0,0,2\pi)$. Plugging this into the rotation matrix gives $S = -I$, which means that a $2\pi$ rotation of the spinor flips its sign, and consequently, a $4\pi$ rotation returns it to normal.

Comment: Ah okay. Is there a physical interpretation for what this flipped sign spinor corresponds to?

Comment: Oh I just found a [paper](http://personal.psu.edu/rq9/HOW/Spinor_theory_1.pdf) explaining physical effects of it.